# How to connect a cylinder/sphere to a flat/curved surface surface?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm wondering how you would attach a cylinder or sphere to a flat surface in edit mode. There are many instances, especially in SciFi where you need to attach a cylinder or sphere to a flat surface in a clean matter. Like in these images there are many cylinders intersecting curved and flat surfaces. I know in some of these images they probably don't have it connected and instead just pass through each other, but how would you connect the meshes in edit mode? 
[image]
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: I voted to close this question because in its present form it is too broad. There are too many ways to attach a cylinder to a flat surface, and the best way to make the attachment in any particular case is likely to be dependent upon the surfaces and the circumstances involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do so. But the question is often, is it necessary. Something artist needs the normals of the meshes to behave appropriately and sometimes the effort just don't really pay for the little returns.

On this video the user is creating an emboss effect on a gold bar. There is alot of times he needs to be joining faces in his video. Link below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0mkoMkEbc0

Although this maybe about embossing text the underlying method of how to join meshes pretty much applies for all cases.

1. Select the edges you want to fill.
2. Subdivide the edge with the lower vertex count to make a closer match the number of vertices.
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to fill.

[image]